# Lifetime of RDF nodes in Redland RDF after parsing a model?

Tags: rdf, redland

I am parsing an RDF_model using `librdf_parser_parse_string_into_model`. I then retain the `librdf_model` but free the `librdf_parser`. It looks to me as if the nodes in the model then have disappeared as well.

So what lifetime does [Redland RDF](http://librdf.org/) impose on `librdf_node`s in this case? Is the the lifetime of the model that contains them (as would seem most convenient) or the lifetime of the parser that created them (as now may be the case)? The documentation seems to be silent on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redland nodes `librdf_node` are implemented as Raptor terms `raptor_term`.  These are reference counted but not cached in any other way, so are `free()`-d when they are no longer referenced.  Similarly `librdf_uri` are `raptor_uri` and work the same way.